"I have to go see a man about a dog"
A guy with blonde hair says this to someone else who is on a horse, the guy who says it has a british accent and I believe the movie was set in a medieval period.  For some reason, I am also picturing the same guy naked in a scene from this movie.
I believe it is an American film, it was actually on TBS when I saw it. I remember some jousting in the movie, I cannot remember any actors, it has been a while (6-7) years since I have seen it.

Please add any details you know: Country of origin (or at least language), estimated year of release (or at least the year you saw it), actors you recognize (or even just what they look like), was it in theaters or only on TV, any other minor plot points.  The more you can give us, the more likely we can help you.

Pretty sure I know what you're after, but yes, more details might help, if you have them.

I believe it is an american film, it was actually on TBS when I saw it.  I remember some jousting in the movie, I cannot remember any actors, it has been a while (6-7) years since I have seen it.

You're looking for A Knight's Tale from 2001.

Inspired by "The Canterbury Tales," as well as the story of Ulrich von Lichtenstein, this is the story of William, a young squire with a gift for jousting. After his master dies suddenly, the squire hits the road with his cohorts Roland and Wat. On the journey, they stumble across an unknown writer, Chaucer. William, lacking a proper pedigree, convinces Chaucer to forge genealogy documents that will pass him off as a knight. With his newly-minted history in hand, the young man sets out to prove himself a worthy knight at the country's jousting competition, and finds romance along the way.

Heath Ledger is the man on the horse, Paul Bettany (as Geoffrey Chaucer) is the blonde naked man with the English accent who says he "has to see a man about a dog". Here's most of the scene:




Yep!  That's it!!!  Am going to netflix it tonight...you guys are so smart on this website, you need to work at NASA or something....

@steelerfan Not that Walt doesn't know I think he's magical, but this was my first thought, too... not too many films with naked guys wandering around.

lol...I see your point!!  You guys are all good on this site :)
